# having trouble with post data to server

Tags: ios, swift, post, httprequest, nsurlconnection

I have problem when i post the data to server, it seems doesn't work at all.. I've found the code thats the other use it for post

here is the code for post

```
func post(params : Dictionary<String, String>, url : String, postCompleted : (succeeded: Bool, msg: String) -> ()) {
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "")!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
//        let postString = "Body: \(personaldata.data)"
        var err: NSError?
//        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            println("Response: \(response)")

            var strData = NSString(CString: personaldata.data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("Body: \(personaldata.data)")
            var err: NSError?
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

            var msg = "No message"

        })

        task.resume()
    }
```

and when the button send pressed, here is the code

```
func tapGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("analisa", sender: self)
    if let Kirim = gesture.view as? UIImageView {  // if you subclass UIImageView, then change "UIImageView" to your subclass
        self.post(["ID":"123", "function_name":"update_db", "personal_information_table":"\(personaldata.data)"], url: "") { (succeeded: Bool, msg: String) -> () in


        }
    }
}
```

the output when println correct already,but it doesn't appear at the website, how it could be?

I hide the website address ( it only shows line with id and weight , height on it that contains in(personaldata.data)
well my friend who working on android, have sent the data successfully :/

[image]

here is the website, and that is my friends data, not mine

is my code error or what?

here is the println

```
Response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe591554d60> { URL: } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = none;
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Fri, 28 Aug 2015 09:34:02 GMT";
    Server = "Google Frontend";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; p=\"1\"; ma=604800";
} }
Body: {"height": 214, "weight": 123}
```

Answer (score 0):

Status code: 500 indicates that the error can only be resolved by fixes to the Web server software. It is not a client-side problem. It is up to the operators of the Web server site to locate and analyse the logs which should give further information about the error.